# How does rails differentiate between users/:id and users/new routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am trying to understand how does rails know the difference between the two routes

`GET /users/:id`

and

`GET /users/new`

when we type

`resources :users`

I tried to trace and understand the resources method in rails source code but I didn't understand it completely.

```
    def resources(*resources, &block)
      options = resources.extract_options!.dup

      if apply_common_behavior_for(:resources, resources, options, &block)
        return self
      end

      with_scope_level(:resources) do
        options = apply_action_options options
        resource_scope(Resource.new(resources.pop, api_only?, @scope[:shallow], options)) do
          yield if block_given?

          concerns(options[:concerns]) if options[:concerns]

          collection do
            get  :index if parent_resource.actions.include?(:index)
            post :create if parent_resource.actions.include?(:create)
          end

          new do
            get :new
          end if parent_resource.actions.include?(:new)

          set_member_mappings_for_resource
        end
      end

      self
    end
```

Is the below piece of code does that?

```
     new do
       get :new
     end if parent_resource.actions.include?(:new)
```

if yes, can you explain?

Also if I tried to write another route with the same `GET users/new` format it redirects to `GET users/:id`, so how can I write another route like `GET users/whatever` without considering *whatever* as the *:id*?

Below is example of routes.rb

Example 1:

```
get   '/feedbacks/:id'  => 'feedbacks#show'
get   '/feedbacks/count'     => 'feedbacks#count'
```

`feedbacks/count` redirects to `/feedbacks/:id`

Example 2:

```
resources :feedbacks
get   '/feedbacks/count'     => 'feedbacks#count'
```

`feedbacks/count` redirects to `/feedbacks/:id`

Comment: How does your routes file look like?

Comment: updated with examples

Comment: Well, you just have to define `get '/feedbacks/count'` _before_ `get   '/feedbacks/:id'`.

Comment: Opss, not sure how I missed that, thanks.

Comment: See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions (the 2nd yellow box)

Comment: Thank you, Stefan. It helped. I know it, but forget it completely. :)

Comment: No worries, the documentation is long and Rails is full of magic ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails does not differentiate, it's just searches for the first record, which is suitable for the conditions

That's why new is generated earlier than id

Example 1:

```
get '/feedbacks/count' => 'feedbacks#count'
get '/feedbacks/:id'   => 'feedbacks#show'
```

Example 2:

```
resources :feedbacks do
  member do
    get '/feedbacks/count' => 'feedbacks#count'
  end
end
```

[You can read about it here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

Comment: You can include quote about routes matching from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions in your  answer :)

Comment: The wording here is really off. Routes don't have anything to do with records - rather routes have priority in the order they are defined.

Answer (score 1):

Rails routes are just basically regular expressions on steriods. They match a path expression, a HTTP method and any additional constraints.

Routes have priority in the order they are defined. When the router matches a request in the routes collection it stops searching farther which is why the routes at the top always win.

If you look at the output from the `resources` macro your can see that the routes are ordered to take this into consideration:

```
     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
    things GET    /things(.:format)          things#index
           POST   /things(.:format)          things#create
 new_thing GET    /things/new(.:format)      things#new
edit_thing GET    /things/:id/edit(.:format) things#edit
     thing GET    /things/:id(.:format)      things#show
           PATCH  /things/:id(.:format)      things#update
           PUT    /things/:id(.:format)      things#update
           DELETE /things/:id(.:format)      things#destroy
```

The `GET /things/new` route must be declared before `GET /things/:id`. Otherwise it would be matched by the `things#show` route and give an `ActiveRecord:: RecordNotFound` error as the controller would attempt to find `Thing id = "new"`.

> users/:id, so how can I write another route like GET users/whatever
>   without considering whatever as the :id?

Use the collection option:

```
resources :things do
  get :foo, on: :collection
end

# same but with block syntax
resources :things do
  collection do
    get :foo
    get :bar
  end    
end
```

You can also add additional member routes (prefixed with an id):

```
resources :trips do
  patch :cancel
end
```

Note that Rails defaults to `on: :member` so you don't need to explicitly set it.

Since `resources` yields at the top (`yield if block_given?`) these routes will have the correct priority.

See:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: Very helpful, Thank you. Another question, does the collection option defines what's using it before the show action as it's done with the new action? Also does the new action is also written with collection option implicitly?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how the source code for resources works but `new do; get :new ... end` is a block that declares a collecton route. I don't know why its seperate from the other collection block. Understanding the meta-programming heavy rails code can be pretty tricky at times and its better to just look at the guides and API docs and try to understand how its supposed to work.

Comment: Another good way to figure out how it works is to try different combinations and run `rake routes` and check the output.

Comment: "does the collection option defines what's using it before the show action as it's done with the new action?" - since the `resources` method yields at the top of the method it is run before any member routes are added. So yes,  they are declared before the show route.